# Probability of sequential successes

Tags: probability

I've looked around and seen some similar questions, but none that seems to exactly anwer my question, and rather than resurrect old, possibly-related, questions, I thought I'd start a new one, so here goes:

Suppose the probably of failure of an action is 20%. Now suppose this action is attempted a maximum of two times, and that attempts stop when a failure occurs. What is the probability that both sequential attempts will be successful.

As I think about this, it seems to me there are two approaches:

1. This one is the easiest, mathematically: Since I'm interested in two successful attempts, the probability can be calculated by finding the probability of success from the given probability of failure, and multiplying, so - 0.8 * 0.8 = 0.64, or 64% chance of success.
2. The more-complicated approach would be to say the probability of failure at the initial event is 0.2, and then within the sub-set of initial successes (0.8 probability) there is another 0.2 probability of a second failure, so - 0.2 + (0.8 * 0.2) = 0.2 + 0.16 = 0.36 = 36% of failure at either point, or 64% of success at both.

One of the other similar questions I'd seen suggested that it would actually be 0.2 + 2 * (0.2 * 0.8), but it seems to me that would be accurate only if both attempts were made, regardless of the result of the first attempt, and you were interested in the probability of not having two failures.

Is my approach above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your approaches are correct.   Since the run ends on a failure, the only outcomes are: "one failure", "one success then one failure", and "two successes".

The first one is straightforward.  Given probability of failure $p$, the probability of "two successes" is: $$(1-p)^2$$

The second one is equivalent.  The probability of one failure at either trial is the sum of the probabilities of "one failure" and "one success then one failure": $$p + (1-p)p=2p-p^2$$Therefore the probability of this not happening is: $$1-2p+p^2 = (1-p)^2$$

---

**Note:**  Assume after the first trial fails the second trial is made, but just not recorded.   We could count the secret outcomes of "two failures" and "one failure then one success".   But the sum of their probabilities is that of the recorded event of "one failure": $$p^2+p(1-p)=p$$

so this is how the event of not having "two successes" could be counted as: $$p^2+p(1-p)+(1-p)p = p^2+2p(1-p)$$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks much! It's been a long time since I've thought about probabilities, and I'm a bit rusty.