# Failure probability in $3^{rd}$ attempt after 2 first failure attempt

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

First, excuse me for my languish.

First i wase have to case sending message one times with failure probability $Q_1=1-P_1$ and successful probability $P_1=exp(-\theta)$,$\theta$ is real number.
Now I send two times so I have
$P_1$ and $Q_1$ also failure probability $Q_2$ on second attempt and successful probability $P_2$ on the second attempt in which 
$P_1+Q_1+P_2+Q_2=1$.

So now I have only $P_1$ and $Q_1$, if someone can help me to find $Q_2$ and $P_2$ in which $Q_2$ failure on second attempt probability after failure in the first attempt.

The geometrical distrubution $P_2=P_1*(1-P_1)$ give me only $P_2$ but i need also $Q_2$ inwich $P_1+Q_1+P_2+Q_2=1$.

So if there is any distrubution or conditional probability to get this probability, the important thing is $P_1=exp(-\theta)$

Thank so much in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, by definition $Q_2 = 1-P_2$.

Comment: My be this is helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981839/probability-of-sequential-successes

Comment: No, i  have modify just it was mistake,

Comment: "$Q_2$ failure on second attempt probability after failure in the first attempt." That is $1-P_2$ by definition. You said also that $P_2 = P_1 \cdot (1-P_1)$, so $Q_2 = 1 - ( P_1 \cdot (1-P_1))$.

Comment: Using geometrical distrubtion it was just idea , o if we use it, we have $Q_2=1-P_2$, we get $P_1+P_2+Q_1+Q_2=2$

Comment: Can we find using tree diagram